# How to disable CrossTab sort order?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports, crosstab

I have a crossTab in  my report that shows:

```
          L    S    XL    Changes    Combination    Material
 Shirt   10         5    something   somethiung    something
 Pants         2    4    something   somethiung    something
```

But I need it to be sorted like this:

```
           Material    Combination     Changes    S    L    XL
 Shirt     something   somethiung    something        10    5
 Pants     something   somethiung    something    2         4
```

Now keep in mind that I already sort the values the way I want them to be sorted in my stored procedure the only problem is that CorssTab has its own sorting and so far I haven't found a way to disable it.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and Crystal Reports 13.0.10 and SQL 2014 (tho i doubt SQL version matters).
I am not allowed to change the version of VS or CR or SQL that I am using.
If needed I can provide you with everything you need in order to 'test' my question if you don't believe that my stored procedure sorts the values in one way but CrossTab ignores it.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/493334/Custom-sorting-for-Crystal-Report-Cross-Tab) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225723/sorting-cross-tab-columns-in-crystal-reports)

This option is available in Cross-tab popup, below the column selection there is "Group option".

[image]

Comment: I can not achieve what I want with that option since when you click it it gives you the option to sort in ascending, descending or specific order. Ascending and descending order are of no use for me and so far I haven't been able to use specific order to achieve what I want. I already figured out the way to use it but thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: what you did just answer it, so that help to others.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Select Case formula that adds the desired sort position as a number before each group value:

1. Material
2. Combination
3. ...

Use that formula for the CrossTab column

Then, use the CrossTab Group Options dialog, Options tab, to 'Customize Group Name Field' with the option to 'Use a formula as Group Name'.
In that expression, return MID({@ColumnFormula}, 4) to throw away the number prefix.